# How can I append more than one DOM inside a Leaflet control?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there a way to append more than one DOM element to a DOM created with L.control?

Basically, I want to place both *distanceFilterContainer* and *elevationFilterContainer* elements inside a container  element. How can I accomplish this?

```
<div  id="distanceFilterContainer">
<input type="checkbox">
.
.
<input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div id="elevationGainFilterContainer">
<input type="checkbox">
.
.
<input type="checkbox">
</div>

<script>
var distanceFilter = L.control({position:'topleft'});
var elevationGainFilter = L.control({position:'topleft'});

distanceFilter.onAdd = function(mymap){
    this._div = L.DomUtil.get('distanceFilterContainer')
    return this._div
}

elevationGainFilter.onAdd = function(mymap){
    this._div = L.DomUtil.get('elevationGainFilterContainer')
    return this._div    
}

distanceFilter.addTo(mymap)
elevationGainFilter.addTo(mymap)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested but the idea is here you have to target your div by ID and append to the new dynamic div created by using createElement and append this div to BODY.

```
var distanceFilter = L.control({position:'topleft'});
var elevationGainFilter = L.control({position:'topleft'});

distanceFilter.onAdd = function(mymap){
    this._div = L.DomUtil.get('distanceFilterContainer')
    return this._div
}

elevationGainFilter.onAdd = function(mymap){
    this._div = L.DomUtil.get('elevationGainFilterContainer')
    return this._div    
}

//create container
var body = document.body;
var container = document.createElement('div');
var div1 = document.getElementById('distanceFilterContainer');
var div2 = document.getElementById('elevationGainFilterContainer');
container.className = "youcontainerclassCSS";
container.appendChild(div1);
container.appendChild(div2);
body.appendChild(container);
distanceFilter.addTo(mymap)
elevationGainFilter.addTo(mymap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply embed your elements in a container ?

```
<div id="map"></div>

<div id="filtersContainer">
  <div  id="distanceFilterContainer">
    <input type="checkbox">. . <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div id="elevationGainFilterContainer">
    <input type="checkbox">. . <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// ...
var filtersContainer = L.control({position:'topleft'});

filtersContainer.onAdd = function(mymap){
    this._div = L.DomUtil.get('filtersContainer')
    return this._div
}

filtersContainer.addTo(map)
</script>
```